# How to get the text from an angular element with text populated from ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

This is the input from which I want to get the text from.

The text is updated using ng-model(i think).

I am unable to get the text from this or clear it.

I am using protractor and jasmine

```
<input type="text" placeholder="HH" ng-model="hours" ng-change="updateHours()"
       class="form-control text-center ng-pristine ng-valid
              ng-valid-hours ng-not-empty ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched"
       ng-readonly="::readonlyInput" maxlength="2" tabindex="1"
       ng-disabled="noIncrementHours()" ng-blur="blur()"
       autocomplete="off" style="">
```

Is there a way to get the text or clear the filed so that I can enter some value by myself.

Comment: the text will be in the ng-model. i.e. in your controller use `$scope.hours" to the the value of input.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the input text ,you can use clear() function for example :

```
input=element(by.css('input.form-control.text-center.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-valid-hours.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-maxlength.ng-touched'));


input.clear();
```

If you want to input a text to the field:

```
input.sendKeys('my input')
```

Comment: already tried using clear(), I am getting a "the field must be user editable to clear it" error. Also getText() is returning empty string and getAttribute is giving null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var input = element(by.model('hours'));
var val = input.getAttribute('value');
input.clear();
```

But i would like to point out the property `ng-readonly="::readonlyInput"` that makes it unable to use clear if  readonlyInput is true in component.
And also check that input is populated with value before your `getText` or `getAttribute` get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below one

```
var input = element(by.css('input.form-control.text-center.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-valid-hours.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-maxlength.ng-touched'));
//To enable the field click on it before getting the text
input.click();
//To get the text i.e: inner html of the element
input.getText();
//To clear the field
input.clear();
```

Hope it helps you...